# SQL count is not upto my desired result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two different table Products and ProductImages:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.productid) AS product_count, COUNT(pi.imageid) AS image_count  
FROM [Products] p, [ProductImages] pi  
WHERE p.productid=126 AND pi.productid=126;
```

Above query is giving me the mulitplication of both counts in each COUNT.
Please guide me where I am wrong and **Can I do it with single select query**.

Comment: Table description please!

Comment: At first sight this doesn't seem to make sense. Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: if p.productid = 126 then COUNT(p.productid) is  > 1 ?

Comment: @Sohail Have you checked for duplicate rows in your table ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this in two rows

```
SELECT COUNT(p.productid) As Count
FROM [Products] p
WHERE p.productid=126
UNION All
SELECT COUNT(pi.imageid) As Count
FROM  [ProductImages] pi 
WHERE pi.productid=126;
```

OR you can do this without **UNION ALL**

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(p.productid) As Count 
From [Products] p WHERE p.productid=126) ) as t1,
(SELECT COUNT(pi.imageid) As Count 
FROM  [ProductImages] pi WHERE pi.productid=126) as t2
```

Comment: can't I get result in single select statement to save cpu cost??

Comment: UNION cannot be use like this. Better take it as two separate queries considering efficiency in cursor sharing!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: UnionAll is used as per requirement. You can read details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: I was trying to say, UNIONs should be used to combine resultsets, and the purpose is misused here. Syntactically it is correct.

Comment: @Sohail: I have edited the answer to best of my knowledge as count() behaviour changes when more tables are combined in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try This by subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(p.productid) AS product_count,(Select COUNT(pi.imageid) AS image_count  [ProductImages] pi  Where pi.productid=126; ) FROM [Products] p  WHERE p.productid=126
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT p.productid) AS product_count ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT pi.imageid) AS image_count
FROM    [Products] p ,
        [ProductImages] pi
WHERE   p.productid = 126
        AND pi.productid = 126 ;
```